# Como criar um conjunto de tabelas no banco de dados via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, mysqli

Eu estou com problemas enquanto a criação do banco de dados de forma automática via PHP.  Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em MVC da faculdade e queria importar o arquivo sql e através de uma query criar as tabelas.

Na parte anterior do código é feita a conexão com o banco de dados e também a criação do banco de dados também via query e ambos funcionam perfeitamente; porém na hora de criar as tabelas nada acontece nem erros, o código é o seguinte:

```
$sql = file_get_contents(BASE_URL."database/arquivo.sql");
echo $sql;
$this->connection->multi_query($sql);
```

Já tentei com `query()` e `multi_query()` e nada acontece, o que pode estar de errado?

Galera, o link do arquivo sql é esse: https://www.dropbox.com/s/edp8uhifnl2mw97/lapesa.sql?dl=0

está indicando o seguinte erro:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_' at line 12
```

Se eu deleto essa linha, o erro continua para as linhas seguintes, não estou conseguindo resolver.

Comment: Poderia colocar parte do conteúdo de arquivo.sql? veja se dessa forma retorna algum erro: `$res = $this->connection->multi_query($sql);
if(!$res){
   echo $this->error;
}`.

Comment: O conteúdo do arquivo sql é gerado pelo phpmyadmin, portanto não tem erros de sintaxe ou algo semelhante, só preciso gerá-lo automaticamente porque terei que exportar o projeto

Comment: Havia esquecido de comentar isso na pergunta

Comment: A tela fica em branco? verificou se a exibição dos erros não está oculta.

Comment: A exibição de erros está habilitada e a tela não ficou branca, está mostrando toda a view montada

Comment: Poderá ser a sua connection...

Comment: Eu testei aqui parte do arquivo sql e tive o mesmo erro, então removi a cabeçalho(comentários) e na tabela `administrador` mudei a chave primária de `id` para `id_admin`

Comment: ai funcionou perfeitamente?

Comment: perfeito, funcionou certíssimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei aqui e todas as tabelas foram cridas mesmo com os comentários/cabeçalhos no arquivo. O único problema foi que em todas as tabelas a chave primária é `id` so que essa coluna não existe em nehuma tabela. Então você corrigir os nomes.

<sub>obs: suprimi alguns campos da tabela deixando apenas o id_algo</sub>

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `administrador` (
  `id_admin` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `apresentacao`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apresentacao` (
  `id_apresentacao` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

O código do teste foi o seguinte:

```
$sql = file_get_contents('sql.sql');

if(!$db->multi_query($sql)){
    echo $db->error;
}else{
    echo 'tabelas criadas com sucesso';
}
```

Utilize [multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) para processar várias instruções sql de uma só vez, lembrando que elas devem ser separadas por ponto e virgula.